# Java Unit Testing JaCoCo

Tags: java, unit-testing, code-coverage, jacoco

I am new to Java and JaCoCo. I have a simple interface and an implementation as below.

```
public interface Action<T>{ T getT(T in); }
public class Foo{...}
public class ActionImpl implements Action<Foo>{ public Foo getT(Foo in);}
```

The class `ActionImpl` only has a default constructor. On writing unit tests for the class `ActionImpl`, JaCoCo reports 100% coverage for the ActionImpl but reports 88% coverage for `ActionImpl.new Object(){...}`.

How do I interpret this report and where does `ActionImpl.new Object(){...}` come from?

Comment: Could you please provide more complete example allowing to reproduce this? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve